# Solaris nfslogd doesn't update logs accorindg to nfslog.conf setting

Tags: unix, nfs, vmware-workstation, solaris-10

I am using solaris-10-(u7-ga-x86) over VMware Workstation 12 over Linux.

I have a problem that nfslogd will never update logs unless I restart the service each time to get new log updates. or it can take random times to update. sometimes it update after few seconds or hours. sometimes it totally stop updating.

I tried to set /etc/nfs/nfslogd

MIN_PROCESS_SIZE=1
   MAX_TIME=1 
to update log as long it is more than 1 byte and MAX_IDLE_TIME to 1 sec
still updates doesn't happen unless I restart nfs/server service or after random times.

Answer (score 0):

after some research. making sure that every entry regarding the nfs version in /etc/default/nfs is "3" solved it for me.